# How to standardize and organize error messages with Hibernate Validator (running under Spring framework)

Tags: java, hibernate-validator

I'm learning Hibernate Validator. I see that I can add an error message text to any annotation.

But this seems like a bad way to handle error messages. It would be cleaner to return an error message ID and look up the message text in some resource file like a Properties file.

In this way I can later extend to other languages by swapping out the particular resource file; and the error messages are organized into one coherent location.

What's the best approach here with Hibernate Validator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.3/reference/en-US/html_single/#chapter-message-interpolation) section in the manual for an approach of i18n error descriptions in Hibernate Validator.

There is another [tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/using-hibernate-validator?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%253A%20javalobby%252Ffrontpage%20%2528Javalobby%20%252F%20Java%20Zone%2529) which might prove handy.

Cheers!

Comment: First link is dead :(